# Accessing value of a variable from other code file

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I have below code

```
import os
os.chdir('<<some folder>>')
import codeFile as CF
```

We have `codeFile.py` file in `<<some folder>>` which I am importing

Now, in `codeFile.py`, there is one line called

```
print(a_Variable)
```

When I execute `import codeFile as CF`, I get error that name `'a_Variable'` is not defined.

So to define that variable, I coded below line

```
import os
os.chdir('<<some folder>>')
a_Variable = 6
import codeFile as CF
```

But still I am getting same error.

Is there any way to make `a_Variable` available for `import codeFile as CF`.

For my reason, I want to define `a_Variable` outside of `codeFile.py`

Any pointer will be very helpful

**Update from the answer from @ProfDFrancis**

@ProfDFrancis provided one solution for above problem. However it appears that this solution is not working for below problem

in `codeFile.py`, I have below lines

```
def My_Fun(args) 
    return args + 10
def My_Fun1(args) 
    return args * 10

def init(a_Variable) :
    if a_Variable == 10 :
        print('RUNNING..')
        def My_Fun(args) :
            return args + 10 + 2
        def My_Fun1(args) :
            return args * (10 + 2)
```

Any in main file, I have below

```
import codeFile as CD
CD.init(10)
CD.My_Fun(100)
```

With this I am expecting I would get value as 112, but actually I am getting 110. Looks like, the first definition of function i.e. `args + 10` is considered not the second definition i.e. `args + 10 + 2`

Any way how to fix this issue will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It looks like you are trying to use `import` as a way of running code with a parameter

A better way to do that is to put that code, that you are currently expecting to be run at import-time, into a function.

#### Inside codeFile

Instead of

```
do something with a_Variable
```

put

```
def initialize(a_Variable):
    do something with a_Variable
```

#### Then in your main file

Import the codeFile, and then subsequently call the relevant function, passing it the value you want to use for `a_Variable`.

```
import os
os.chdir('<<some folder>>')
import codeFile as CF
CF.initialize(6)
```

#### To create two different versions of `My_Fun`

The problem with the previous approach is that the `My_Fun` is created only within the scope of `initialize`. Once that function ends, the special variant of `My_Fun` that is indeed created, is destroyed, so that in the main scope of the CodeFile, there is only the "outside" definition.

But there is an easy way round it: create a function that *creates* a version of `My_Fun` and then *returns it*. Use the *returned* function in future.

###### main.py

```
import codeFile as CD

my_fun = CD.create_my_fun(0)
print("When created with 0, my_fun(1) returns", my_fun(1))

my_fun = CD.create_my_fun(10)
print("When created with 10, my_fun(1) returns", my_fun(1))
```

###### codeFile.py

```
def create_my_fun(a_Variable):
    if a_Variable == 10:

        def my_fun(args):
            print("Running special version")
            return args + 10 + 2

    else:

        def my_fun(args):
            print("Running standard version")
            return args + 10

    return my_fun   # <---- This is the critical part: return the function, rather than simply letting it be destroyed when this function ends.
```

#### Result

```
Running old version
When created with 0, my_fun(1) returns 11       
Running new version
When created with 10, my_fun(1) returns 13
```

It may feel slightly weird to be make a function that returns a function, but there are whole branches of software engineering that actually live like this and think it is normal! So don't worry.

Comment: thanks for your awesome answer. However I found that this approach is not working in some complex cases e.g. definition of function. I have modified my original post with such an example. Any way how to make this approach more general?